# I am using api to make a page dynamic using pagination -hooks but i am getting error. TypeError: posts.slice is not a function

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-hooks

I am using slice function in post but it gives the error. should I not use slice?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Posts from "./components/Posts";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";
 
function App() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [currPage, setCurrPage] = useState(1);
    const [postsPerPage] = useState(5);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            let res = await axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

            setPosts(res.data);
            setLoading(false);
        };
        fetchData();
    },
 []);
 
    //get current post  const indexOfLastPost = currPage * postsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
    const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
 
    const paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrPage(pageNumber);
 
    return (        <div className='container m-4'>             <h4>My Blog</h4>
            <Posts posts={currentPosts} loading={loading} />            <Pagination
                postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
                totalPosts={posts.length}
                paginate={paginate}             />      </div>  ); }
 
 export default App;
```

Comment: To help understand what is going on here, can you console.log the object 'posts'? It may not be an array

Comment: Sure. will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Slice uses for array. Are u sure posts after filling by api is array yet? please check this